# Is it bad practice to modify attributes of one module from another module?

Tags: python

I want to define a bunch of config variables that can be imported in all the modules in my project. The values of those variables will be constant during runtime but are not known before runtime; they depend on the input. Usually I'd define a *dict* in my top module which would be passed to all functions and classes from other modules; however, I was thinking it may be cleaner to simply create a blank *config.py* module which would be dynamically filled with config variables by the top module:

```
# top.py
import config
config.x = x

# config.py
x = None

# other.py
import config
print(config.x)
```

I like this approach because I don't have to save the parameters as attributes of classes in my other modules; which makes sense to me because parameters do not describe classes themselves.

This works but is it considered bad practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question as such may be disputed. But I would generally say yes, it's "bad practice" because scope and impact of change is really getting blurred. Note the use case you're describing really is not about sharing configuration, but about different parts of the program functions, objects, modules exchanging data and as such it's a bit of a variation on (meta)`global` variable).

Reading common configuration values could be fine, but changing them along the way... you may lose track of what happened where and also in which order as modules get imported / values get modified. For instance assume the `config.py` and two modules `m1.py`:

```
import config
print(config.x)
config.x=1
```

and `m2.py`:

```
import config
print(config.x)
config.x=2
```

and a `main.py` that just does:

```
import m1
import m2
import config
print(config.x)
```

or:

```
import m2
import m1
import config
print(config.x)
```

The state in which you find config in each module and really any other (incl. `main.py` here) depends on order in which imports have occurred and who assigned what value when. Even for a program entirely under your control, this may get confusing (and source of mistakes) rather quickly.

For runtime data and passing information between objects and modules (and your example is really that and not configuration that is predefined and shared between modules) I would suggest you  look into describing the information perhaps in a custom state (config) object and pass it around through appropriate interface. But really just a function / method argument may be all that is needed. The exact form depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve and what your overall design is.

---

In your example, `other.py` behaves differently when called or imported before `top.py` which may still seem obvious and manageable in a minimal example, but really is not a very sound design. Anyone reading the code (incl. future you) should be able to follow its logic and this IMO breaks its flow.

The most trivial (and procedural) example of what for what you've described and now I hopefully have a better grasp of would  be `other.py` recreating your current behavior:

```
def do_stuff(value):
    print(value)  # We did something useful here

if __name__ == "__main__":
   do_stuff(None)  # Could also use config with defaults
```

And your `top.py` presumably being the entry point and orchestrating importing and execution doing:

```
import other
x = get_the_value()
other.do_stuff(x)
```

You can of course introduce an interface to configure `do_stuff` perhaps a `dict` or a custom class even with default implementation in `config.py`:

```
class Params:
    def __init__(self, x=None):
        self.x = x
```

and your `other.py`:

```
def do_stuff(params=config.Params()):
    print(params.x)  # We did something useful here
```

And on your `top.py` you can use:

```
params = config.Params(get_the_value())
other.do_stuff(params)
```

But you could also have any use case specific source of value(s):

```
class TopParams:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.x = get_value_from_url(url)

params = TopParams("https://example.com/value-source")
other.do_stuff(params)
```

`x` could even be a `property` which you retrieve every time you access it... or lazily when needed and then cached... Again, it really then is a matter of what you need to do.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough but the values of config variables will be set by the top module and will not change throughout the runtime.

Comment: @waterlemon I've tried to extend it a bit, does that better address your question?

Answer (score 1):

"Is it bad practice to modify attributes of one module from another module?"

that it is considered as bad practice - violation of the law of demeter, which means in fact "talk to friends, not to strangers".

Objects should expose behaviour and functions, but should HIDE the data.
DataStructures should EXPOSE data, but should not have any methods (which are exposed). The law of demeter does not apply to such DataStructures. OOP Purists might cover such DataStructures with setters and getters, but it really adds no value in Python.

there is a lot of literature about that like : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter

and of course, a must to read: "Clean Code", by Robert C. Martin (Uncle Bob), check it out on Youtube also.

For procedural programming it is perfectly normal to keep data in a DataStructure which does not have any (exposed) methods.

The procedures in the program work with that data. Consider to use the module `attrs`, see : https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/ for easy creation of such classes.

my prefered method for keeping config is (here without using attrs):

```
# conf_xy.py
"""
config is code - so why use damned parsers, textfiles, xml, yaml, toml and all that
if You just can use testable code as config that can deliver the correct types, etc.
as well as hinting in Your favorite IDE ?
Here, for demonstration without using attrs package - usually I use attrs (read the docs)

"""

class ConfXY(object):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x: int = 1
        self.z: float = get_z_from_input()
        ...

conf_xy=ConfXY()
```

```
# other.py

from conf_xy import conf_xy

...

y = conf_xy.x * 2

...
```

Comment: I like this but this requires the values be known before runtime. My values depend on the input. If I define this object in the top module that receives the input, I cannot import this module in all other modules since this module will be calling other modules. Thus, I need to pass the object around and save it as an attribute of all other classes from other modules - and I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: those data objects dont have to be static. 
look now at self.z - it is read from some input.

And You can import that config from were You want - as long as You dont have a circular import !

Comment: Why is this better than modifying the module attributes directly? Because I'm keeping object's attributes separate from the module attributes?

Comment: imagine that is the basic config for a rocket. fuel = 100%, x=0, y=0, z=y, etc ...
and then - how to populate config´s for 100 rockets ? Here it is easy - just create 100 config objects.....

Comment: Using the rocket analogy, this is my use case... I have a rocket.py which contains a Rocket class with attributes describing rockets such as position, type and fuel volume. I also have tanks.py and infantry.py. I have a top module that creates and contains all objects and triggers their actions. I also have many attributes that are relevant for all three classes such as temperature, altitude, fog of war, etc. Instead of passing those attributes to all classes, I want to define them once and fetch them easily in all modules.

Comment: there are three approaches : procedural programming, object oriented programming or functional programming. Which one to choose depends on the structure of the problem.

https://academind.com/learn/javascript/functional-vs-oop-vs-procedural/
https://medium.com/@LiliOuakninFelsen/functional-vs-object-oriented-vs-procedural-programming-a3d4585557f3